# Recursion based array issue

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, scope

I am trying to complete a high school programming project, but one bug is preventing me from finishing. The program/project is meant to solve the 'Non-Attacking Queens' puzzle, which is to find all positions of queens on a chessboard in which there is not two queens in the same row, column, or diagonal. We were required to use recursion to solve this.

Now, the issue that I am running into is two-fold. First, each time I add a solution to the `solvedChessBoards` array at a specific index, all of the elements of the array update to this newest solution, despite me using only one index in the assignment. This means that once I have solved for all possible solutions, my array only contains one solution (the last one added) but just several times.

The second problem is that once the `solveBoard()` method finishes execution, the `solvedChessBoards` array loses all of its values, despite being a class variable. This is problematic when I try to print all of the solutions out, as the array no longer contains any information.

I think this issue stems in a misunderstanding with recursion and how data is stored in java. I was hoping that someone could not only help me with my problem, but 'teach' me what I was doing wrong so that I can avoid similar issues in the future.

Note that while the other methods in the `Board` class are important, I do not believe that the bug originates in any method other than the `solveBoard` method. For this reason, I think that the only reverent code is within this method.

Here is the code for my `Board` class:

```
/**
 * Class that creates a board of given equal dimensions. Also has methods and variables pertaining to 
 * Queen chesspieces that can be placed on the board.
 * 
 * @Andrew Smith 
 * @2/14/16
 */
public class Board
{
    private int solvedBoardCount;
    private final int QUEEN = 1, EMPTY = 0;
    private int expectedSolutions;
    private int[][] chessBoard;
    private int[][][] solvedChessBoards; 
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Creates a chess Board object with given dimensions. Each Board is square, with equal sides.
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Board (int dimension, int solutions) {
        chessBoard = new int[dimension][dimension];
        expectedSolutions = solutions;
        solvedChessBoards = new int[expectedSolutions][dimension][dimension];
        solveBoard(0, chessBoard);
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Creates the default chess Board object with dimensions of 4 on each side.
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Board () {
        chessBoard = new int[4][4];
        solvedChessBoards = new int[1][4][4];
        solveBoard(0, chessBoard);
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // This method does two things.
    // First, it solves the given chess board under the rules of the "Non-Attacking Queens" puzzle. It does this recursively, iterating through
    // all possible combinations of queen placement.
    //
    // Secondly, the method solves for every possible solution to the puzzle, and cataloges these solution 'boards' in the variable 
    // solvedChessBoards, a three dimensional array of 2 dimensional boards.
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private void solveBoard(int row, int[][] tempBoard) {
        for (int column = 0; column < tempBoard.length; column++) { //Goes across the columns of a given row
            if (indexIsSafe(row, column)) { //Checks to see if the queen placement is valid
                tempBoard[row][column] = QUEEN; //Sets placevalue of 1
                if (row < tempBoard.length - 1) { //Unless the board has been solved
                    solveBoard(row+1, tempBoard);
                    deleteLastPosition(row);
                }else{
                    solvedChessBoards[solvedBoardCount] = tempBoard; //Adds solved chessboard to the array
                    solvedBoardCount++; 
                    deleteLastPosition(row);
                } 
            }
        }
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Takes a current row and column and tests to see if it is a viable spot for a queen.
    // This would mean no queens above or in a diagonal path.
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private boolean indexIsSafe(int currentRow, int currentColumn) { //Tests the current index; Returns True if a queen can be placed
        int diagonal = 1; //Used to add/subtract in order to line up the diagonals of the chess board
        for (int testRow = currentRow - 1; testRow >= 0; testRow--) {
            if (chessBoard[testRow][currentColumn] == 1) { //Queen directly ABOVE
                return false;
            }
            //First checks to make sure there is an index to the left
            if (currentColumn - diagonal >= 0 && chessBoard[testRow][currentColumn - diagonal] == 1) { //Queen on LEFT DIAGONAL
                return false;
            }
            //First checks to make sure there is an index to the right
            if (currentColumn + diagonal < chessBoard.length && chessBoard[testRow][currentColumn + diagonal] == 1) { //Queen on RIGHT DIAGONAL
                return false;
            }
            diagonal += 1; //Adjusts for the increasing distance of diagonals
        }
        return true; //A queen can be placed at the current index
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Deletes the last position (1 row above) in the given board. This is used to allow the program to progress along the columns without
    // containing past queen placements.
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private void deleteLastPosition (int currentRow) {
        for (int column = 0; column < chessBoard.length; column++) { //Finds the queen in the row above the current row
                    if (chessBoard[currentRow][column] == 1) {
                        chessBoard[currentRow][column] = EMPTY;
                    }
        }
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Prints the chess Board by returning a formatted string.
    // Empty spaces are represented by 0s, and queens by 1's.
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public String toString () {
      String result = "";
      for (int[][] solvedBoard: solvedChessBoards) {
          for (int row = 0; row < solvedBoard.length; row++) {
              for (int column = 0; column < solvedBoard.length; column++) {
                  result += solvedBoard[row][column];
              }
              result += "\n";
          }
          result += "\n--------------------------------------------- \n";
      }
      return result;
    }
}
```

...and my driver class:

```
/**
 * Solves the Non-Attacking Queens Problem. In order to solve this riddle, a set of Queens must be placed
 * on a blank chess board in a way that no queen is in the same column, row, or diagonal.
 * 
 * @Andrew Smith
 * @1/3/16
 */
public class QueensDriver
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Board chessBoard = new Board(8,92); 
        System.out.print (chessBoard);
    }
}
```

For those willing to help, thank you very very much in advance.

Comment: This line: `solvedChessBoards[solvedBoardCount] = tempBoard;` does not make a copy of the array referenced by `tempBoard` - you are storing a new reference to it in the `solvedChessBoards` array, and then continuing to modify it via the `tempBoard` reference.

Comment: You need to actually copy the array when you store it. I am extremely rusty with Java, so I can't tell you how to copy a 2d array, but that's something to google, at least.

Comment: Also a small style point: it's generally frowned upon to do work in a constructor. I'd make `solveBoard` a separate call.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. For the 'work in the constructor', I did not originally have that method call in there, but I thought that maybe the data loss had something to do with the method call being in the driver rather than the class itself. This didn't make much sense, but I was trying everything I could think of.

Comment: You were absolutely right, the copying of the alias was the source of both problems that I was encountering. Can't thank you enough